# Format date before query database: casts and mutatores

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

The front end of my application consumes the following date format: **d-m-Y h:m:s**

To achieve this , I use protected $casts in the model:

```
protected $casts = [
  'created_at' => 'datetime: d-m-Y h:m:s',
  'updated_at' => 'datetime: d-m-Y h:m:s',
];
```

Works well (for output).

The problem is when, for example, I want to get data from the database within a date range.

In this case, the date is sent to the server side in the following format **01-02-2022**.

For the query to work correctly, the date must previously be in the format **2022-02-01**.

I tried to solve it with a mutator, but it is not working.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;


protected $fillable = [
        ...
        'created_at'
];


public function setCreatedAtAttribute($value)
{
        $this->attributes['created_at'] = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value)->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

Comment: Consider using a different property for output, like `getCreatedAtFormattedAttribute(){ return $this->created_at->format('d-m-Y h:m:s'); }`, and don't touch the actual `created_at` property. That way, you don't need to override `created_at` in multiple places; you can just do `$model->created_at_formatted` when you need to output in that format.

Comment: Thanks TIm Lewis.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common design pattern for me, as Laravel conveniently allows us to overload `newQuery()` in a '`BaseModel`' class, and extend from this class in all our other Models:
you may Override Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model 's query()!

```
/**
 * Overrides Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model 's query()
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
{
    $query = parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted)->where('created_at',$this->getCreatedAt());

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks MIlad Elyasi. How specifically would you implement this solution in my specific case. It's about changing the format of dates before the queries do their work

Comment: This code should place in your model. It will be executed before any query on your model! So you will be able to correct your created at and pass it to your query before any action is done.

Comment: I suppose I have to adapt your function to my specific case. right. Where does $this->getCreatedAt() come from?

Comment: Try to set a function in your model to correct incoming created at just like what you’ve set before in setCreatedAtAttribute